# EOF Error occurs when trying to give a user input

Tags: python, input, eof

I am learning python and have the following code in test.py:

```
string = input()
print(string)
```

Contrary to tutorials, it gives me an error:

```
    string = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

I have no idea what I do wrong here! Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have an `EOFError` exception when running your code. `EOFError` is short for "End-of-Line Error." This error occurs when Python has reached the end of user input without receiving any input.

The reason that `EOFError` occurs is that Python attempts to print out your input in variable `string` when no data is given.

Generally, this error shouldn't pop up when you press your Enter key as input as it registers the variable as a string in your code. It can be manually triggered with the following keystrokes:

- Windows: `Ctrl + Z` -> `Enter`
- macOS/Linux: `Ctrl + D` -> `Enter`

I'd recommend rerunning your program with the same code as it is not likely for an `EOFError` to appear. Try to avoid using the above keystrokes when the program requires input so the error doesn't appear.

If you don't want to see the error in your program, try handling the error and performing another action like printing a string. The code block I've typed prints "no data provided to input function" if an EOFError exception occurs.

```py
try:
     string = input()
     print(string)
except EOFError:
     print("no data provided to input function")
```

If you are a beginner, this snippet won't be needed as you start in Python. Just for a friendly tip, you should name variables relevant to their purpose (ex: naming the sum of two numbers sum1 instead of integer). Naming it after its datatype is okay for very short-term uses but AFAIK is not conventional in any coding language.

(my first answer for StackOverflow...)

Official Documentation: [EOFError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#EOFError)

Comment: Thanks. I runt he code on VS Code under "Run Without Debugging". I don't press any key. What I want is that it asks me to enter a variable and then prints it.

Comment: @Dalalama231123 In your case, your program does ask you to enter a form of input. The reason why it doesn't have any message is that you have to manually add a question when you want it to appear in Python. This can be done by passing a string into the input function. When you run your program, the question should appear and it will look like it asks you a question! Example: string = input("say something");print(string)

Answer (score -1):

> Check what you get from readline() and if it's empty avoid EOF error by
> checking content:

> ```
>   file1 = open("some_file", "r")
>   pack_a = 1
>   while pack_a:
>       pack_a = file1.readline()
>       pack_a = pack_a .replace(',', ' ').split()
>       if pack_a != []:
>      # last element will be iqual to []
> ```

Comment: OP makes no mention at all of a file to read. This answer is not answering the question.